# Optimal way for grouping *provided* dependencies

Tags: java, maven

We have a multi-module POM, which also serves as a parent POM for all sub-modules involved. Call it `MultiModulePOM`. We have about 70 modules, say numbered `Module1` to `Module70`.

Now: The first 30 of these modules require a set of JAR files at compile-time *only*. That is - `scope=provided`. Since we're talking about a *set* of JAR files, it is quite tedious to keep those 30 modules in sync and in general, I am not a huge fan of copying definitions around.

So, I fell into the pitfall of [dependency grouping](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-grouping-dependencies/). Seemed like a good idea, however it doesn't work for `provided` dependencies. In other words: if I group the dependent JARs in a module called `ExtDependencies`, and make `Module1` depend on `ExtDependencies`, the JARs referred-to by `ExtDependencies` won't be transitively-added to `Module1`, because their scope is `provided`.

(If the last paragraph is not true, please let me know as it could really get me out of a jam)

The only other option that I could see was to create a parent POM called (for example) `IntermediaryPOM`. `IntermediaryPOM` extends `MultiModulePOM` and enlists the set of dependent JAR files with `scope=provided`. Modules `Module1`-`Module30` then extend `IntermediaryPOM`.

That seemed to do the trick but I have three problems with it:

1. It adds another layer of POM that I'm not sure is really needed.
2. Later, during distribution time, I find myself having to install/deploy the intermediary POM's as well.
3. Consider the general case: the intermediary POM may have other siblings used for other sets of JARs (for modules 31-50). Therefore, this solution doesn't seem to scale well.

So my question is - according to your experience, what is the best way to approach this? any known best practices for such a use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no easy solution here.

You're right saying that if you declare common dependencies in `ExtDependencies` as `provided` they won't be added to the classpath of any other module that is dependent on `ExtDependencies`. That's how `provided` works.

But you could declare these common dependencies without scope (e.g. with default `compile` scope) and add `provided` dependency on `ExtDependencies`. In this case all of the `ExtDependencies` dependencies *will* be added to classpath. God, that's a lot of *"dependencies"* :)

You've also mentioned other possible option -- introduce another level of abstraction (which, as you might know, is a way to solve almost any problem). But such multi-level hierarchy is less elegant and more difficult to maintain (I have it in our projects, so I've been there).

In general, I haven't come across this problem in such a scale but if I were to solve it I'd go with the first option taking into account scoping suggestion.

Comment: Hmmmmmm. That I didn't think of... common dependencies with scope=compile, and the `ExtDependencies` with scope=provided. I'm going to give it a shot now... +1 regardless though